# MS Excel - Add only selected values in drop down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

My first question about Excel as I was assigned to create a report.
After watching videos from I was able to create a drop down list. However I am not getting how to add only selected values in my drop down.

Here is how my data looks like:

```
Emp Name        Title
-------         ------
Name 1          HR
Name 2          HR
Name 3          Manager
Name 4          HR
Name 5          Manager
```

I want to create a drop down list where I want to keep the HR names

I am sorry, I don't know how to add code or give more information here about what I have done so far.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly. You have use a helper column. In below screenshot I have put following formula to <kbd>**F2**</kbd> cell to filter names of `HR` department.

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,B2:B6="HR")
```

Then use `=F2#` to data validation rule as list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I see FILTER function is available in Office 365. I have MS Excel 2010. any idea how to do this?

Comment: For `Excel-2010` you have to use legacy array formula. Try this formula as array entry `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6="HR",ROW($B$2:$B$6)-ROW($B$1),""),ROW(1:1))),"")` then use name manager.

Comment: Also previous versions will not support `#` hast operator.